# MongoDB sort examine too many records on an indexed column

Tags: mongodb, sorting

while using mongodb sort function I noticed that it's examining too many records, but If I didn't use sort it examine only 22 documents and returns them.

I'm trying to get users who bought some products in DESC order.

both `products.userIDs` and `orderTime` are indexed

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{'products.userIDs':{$in:usersArray}} , {'item.userIDs':{$in:usersArray}}]})
.sort({orderTime:-1})
.explain();
```

without sort it docs examined are 22
with sort docs examined are 1602

how can I sort the documents without examine too many documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo only uses a single index per query (unless there's an `$or`). If you want to have that particular query be well indexed, you'd want to have an index on `{"products.userIDS": 1, "orderTime": 1}`. That way, when it finds the documents, they'll already be sorted & it won't need to to do it in memory. The [compound index docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) have more details.

Comment: What if I have `OR` in my query, do I need to index that with the fields you mentioned?

Comment: $or queries can use different indexes for the different queries in each of the $ors, so if you had something like `{$or: [{a: "foo"}, {b: "bar"]}`, mongo could use an index like `{a: 1}`  to fetch documents matching `{a: "foo" }` and an index like `{b: 1}` to look for the `{b: "bar"}`s. I don't think it's relevant to what you were asking about though -- I just wanted to be clear that mongo _normally_ uses a single index per query (and can't leverage multiple indexes) except when there's something ilke an $or.

Comment: actually I have $or in my query and I tried with and without it and the same result, that's why I set the query without $or because I saw no different, but as I have $or what can I do?

Comment: If the fields are the same in each of the $ors, it shouldn't matter. If you're adding a sort, you'll want to add the field that you're sorting on to your compound index. It's worth reading through the docs for compound indexes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

Comment: I have read that many times, and I did create a compound index on multiple fields but still that same problem. I have edited my query so you take a look at. as your answer do you think that I need to create index for the `orderDate` ,`item.userIDs` and `products.userIDs`?

Comment: If you have an index like `{product.userIDs: 1, item.userIDs: 1, orderDate: 1}` (not necessarily in that order), things should perform OK.

Comment: the order (asc - desc) isn't important even if I'm going to sort descendingly

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work, I can't index  parallel arrays, mongodb says: cannot index parallel arrays

Comment: Yes, you can only have a single array field in a multikey index. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/ You should choose whichever field has the highest cardinality and index both it and orderDate, or revisit your schema structure

Comment: the solution was to create two separate indexes for each array `{ item.userIDs: 1, orderDate: 1}` and {product.userIDs: 1,orderDate: 1}